# Chicken Scheme pass on parameters to gcc

Tags: gcc, scheme, chicken-scheme

In Chicken Scheme, can I pass on certain values that will be given to gcc?
I would like to pass on the following options to the gcc but I don't know how:

```
-lX11 -lpthread -lXinerama -lXext -lGL -g -lm -ldl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [litro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347275/litro) I found the the answer. The following worked for me:

```
csc main.scm lib.o -L "-lX11" -L "-lpthread" -L "-lXinerama" -L "-lXext" -L "-lGL" -L "-g" -L "-lm" -L "-ldl"
```

or

```
csc main.scm lib.o -L "-lX11 -lpthread -lXinerama -lXext -lGL -g -lm -ldl"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass options from `csc` to the C compiler via the `-C` switch and to the linker via the `-L` switch (see `csc -help`).